# Accessing multi-dimensional list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list as follows in my python script:

```
a = [["iguana","i"],["mycat","m"]]
```

I want to access individual elements of the list and print them:

```
print a[0,0]
print a[1,1]
```

But this throws "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple".

How can I access individual elements of the list?

Thanks

Comment: try doing `a[0][0]` . Think of it as a list of lists - `a[0]` returns `["iguana","i"]` and then calling `[0]` on that returns `"iguana"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Index them one at a time:

```
>>> a = [["iguana","i"],["mycat","m"]]
>>> a[0]
['iguana', 'i']
>>> a[0][0]
'iguana'
>>> a[1][0]
'mycat'
>>>
```

The first `[n]` indexes list `a`, which returns a list, and the second indexes *that* list.

Comment: This is the best and easiest solution without resorting to nested loops or other, more verbose code.